# kendoui: Bind Remote datasource to drop down list in template

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a edit template using a list view and want a drop down list that is populated from a remote source. But the drop down list just shows the loading icon.

Here is the DropDownList DataSource.

```
var dsTitles = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: "../data/options/",
        dataType: "json"
    },
    serverFiltering: true,
    filter: [{
        field: "category_opt",
        operator: "eq",
        value: "title"
    }]
});
```

and here is what I'm putting in the edit template

```
<input name="title_clt"
       data-bind="value:title_clt"
       data-value-field="value_opt"
       data-text-field="label_opt"
       data-source="dsTitles"
       data-role="dropdownlist"
       required
       validationMessage="Required" />
```

any help would be great.

Comment: Is this using Kendo Mobile? If you test it in a web browser and look in the dev tools, does the network call return from the server and finish? Are there any JS errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is basically fine **but** there a couple of question that you might have missed.

Since you are defining the DataSource saying `data-source="dsTitles"` as part of the HTML the order on how you define things is pretty important.

The first thing that gets defined is the HTML. Which means that `dsTitle` should be global.
Then, after the `input` is processed is when you should call `kendo.init`.

So, it should be something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>OnaBai - KendoUI DrowDownList</title>
    <!-- Kendo UI Web styles-->
    <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <!-- Kendo UI Web scripts-->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Web Page styling -->
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dsTitles = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: "../data/options/",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            serverFiltering: true,
            filter: [{
                field: "category_opt",
                operator: "eq",
                value: "title"
            }]
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            kendo.init("input");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input name="title_clt"
       data-bind="value:title_clt"
       data-value-field="value_opt"
       data-text-field="label_opt"
       data-source="dsTitles"
       data-role="dropdownlist"
       required
       validationMessage="Required" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I still cant get this working, heres a link to a [test page](http://login.chandlersimmons.co.uk/clients/dropdownlist.php), thanks again

Comment: The problem is in the data returned by `../data/options` that has the array with data enclosed in parenthesis (). Try opening http://login.chandlersimmons.co.uk/data/options/ and you will see it.

Comment: In addition, use `kendo.init("#window-main > input");` since your page has more than one HTML `input`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer might be as simple as using a Kendo DropDownListFor, which will be populated with the given data.